# String byte data to byte array

Tags: android, arrays

"Photo":"[B@3b8ecc3" 
how to store this data into byte [] in android

String photo =object1.getString("Photo");

byte [] photono= photo.getBytes();

"Photo":"[B@3b8ecc3"  json value

How to store same value into  byte [] photono with out change byte value

Comment: what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: What is the datatype of object1? Why do you have a String named photo? If you are trying to get the String value "Photo\":\"[B@3b8ecc3" as a byte[] the getBytes() function should work. You may want to specify your charset by using the getBytes() overload though

Comment: {"Photo":"[B@3b8ecc3" }  this json data to byte array .problem is that  getBytes() function change the original value .